# Options for invoking methods dynamically in C#

Tags: c#, reflection, methods, intermediate-language, invocation

I've seen quite a few questions related to how do I invoke a method like this and that. What I haven't found is a listing of the different options of how to invoke a method via reflection or any other means in csharp.

Can someone explain in detail the different ways of dynamically invoking a method in csharp? From reflection to emitting IL and any other ways in between. I would like to know of all the different ways from most expensive to least expensive in terms of resources.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get you started, here are the ways to invoke a method in .NET that I can think of:

- `Call`
- `Callvirt`
- `Delegate`
- `DynamicMethod`
- `MethodInfo.Invoke`
- `Type.InvokeMember`
- `TypeDescriptor`
- `Reflection.Emit`
- `Expression` Trees

I remember some article comparing the speed of most of them, but I can't seem to find it at the moment.

A quick Google search came up with these links: [[Link]](http://blogs.msdn.com/joelpob/archive/2004/04/01/105862.aspx) [[Link]](http://www.cookcomputing.com/blog/archives/000356.html) [[Link]](http://www.justnbusiness.com/post/2009/09/01/Dynamically-Compiled-Lambdas-vs-Pure-Reflection.aspx) [[Link]](http://sharplearningcurve.com/blog/post/2009/08/19/Dynamic-Access-Method-Performance-Comparison.aspx) [[Link]](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/653034.aspx)

Comment: can you provide code snippets of the most popular ones? Are these arranged by performance cost?

Comment: And of course, the "dynamic" feature in C# 4 uses all of the above. :-)